# Google Sheets - How to reference a URL in 1 column, text in another column, and put result as a clickable link in a new column for EVERY row of data?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

EXAMPLE:

I have one column with a song name (text only) [COLUMN A].

I have another column with a link to that song somewhere else on the Internet [COLUMN B].

I want to create a new column [Column C], and insert a formula on the second row (because the 1st row is the column name/header), that will reference the data in both columns A and B, and put them together so the result will then show as a clickable link for each row in column C.

Columns A and B can be hidden, so only column C shows with the result for each row

I am doing something similar for another column that converts MILLISECONDS from one column into SECONDS using the below formula, which is placed on the second row of the otherwise empty column (except for row 1 which is the column header/name) where the result will show in each row of that column. All cells in each row of this the column below the formula MUST be empty for the result to appear.

=ArrayFormula(if(M2:M="",,M2:M/3600000/24))

...where M represents the column with the MILLISECONDS data in it, and 2 represents the 2nd row, where the formula is placed, with all rows below it empty so the result can be placed there...

If you are still not sure what I am trying to explain, maybe if you know exactly what I am doing you will understand. Here is a text file that explains it in gory detail:

http://noyou.net/spotify/Spotify_and_Google_Sheets.txt

I am not sure how to construct a formula to do what I want as explained above, to combine a text item from one column with a URL from another column with the result shown (via the formula) in each row of a new otherwise empty column.

I know how to do it one row at a time, but I want a formula to do it for all rows and place the result automatically.

One row at a time works with this:

**=hyperlink(H2,N2)**, where H=url column, N=song name column, and the number is for the row.  But I do not want to add that same formula to each and every row, incrementing the number in the formula for each row.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
=ArrayFormula(IF(A2:A="",,HYPERLINK(B2:B,A2:A)))
```